# Is the number of FLOPs in backpropagation double the number of FLOPs in forward propagation?

Tags: neural-networks

In OpenAI's post [AI and Compute](https://openai.com/blog/ai-and-compute/) the authors include the following estimate for the number of FLOPs in ResNet:

> (add-multiplies per forward pass) * (2 FLOPs/add-multiply) * (3 for forward and backward pass) * (number of examples in dataset) * (number of epochs)
> = (11.4 * 10^9) * 2 * 3 * (1.2 * 10^6 images) * 128
> = 10,000 PF = 0.117 pfs-days

I am confused about why they introduce a factor of 3 to account for both forward and backward propagation. To me, this seems to imply that the amount of operations in backprop is twice as much as in a forward pass.

Is this correct? If so, is is specific to ResNet-like architectures or more general?

Comment: This [link](https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/fnjKpBoWJXcSDwhZk/what-s-the-backward-forward-flop-ratio-for-neural-networks) may be useful - the derivation implies that the ratio is approximately 2:1.

Comment: @mohsaied I wrote that post :sweat-smile: